# How to broadcast a message to a list of processes in Erlang? Console hanging

Tags: erlang, erlang-shell

I am new to Erlang and I am trying to understand how to send a message from one process to a list of processes.

Supposedly we have a data structure that holds a list with elements containing a string and Pid. How can I make a Pid send a message "M" to Pids that are one of the two elements previously described ?
What I have come up with is:

```
broadcast(P, M, R) ->
  P ! {self(), friends},
  receive
    {P, Friends} ->
  P ! {self(), {send_message, {M, R, P, Friends}}}
  end.

looper({Name, Friends, Messages}) ->
receive
  {From, friends} ->
    From ! {self(), Friends},
    looper({Name, Friends, Messages});
  {From, {send_message, {M, R, ID, [{FriendPid, FriendName} | FriendTale]}}} ->
    if R =< 0 ->
          From ! {From, {self(), {ID, M}}},
          looper({Name, [{FriendPid, FriendName} | FriendTale], [{ID, M} | Messages]});
       R > 0  andalso FriendTale =/= []->
         FriendPid ! {From, {send_message, {M, R-1, ID, FriendTale}}},
         looper({Name, FriendTale, [{ID, M} | Messages]})
    end;
   terminate ->
    ok
end.
```

But from what I understand is that I don't pattern match correctly the list of Pids so that I can "extract" the Pid from an element of the list of Pids, or I don't correctly use the list to send a message to it.

Basically, I have a function called "looper" that is constantly waiting for new messages to arrive. When it receives a message of type

```
{send_message, {M, R, ID, [{FriendPid, FriendName} | FriendTale]}}
```

where "M" is the message that I want to broadcast to the list of Pids called "Friends" and R is just an integer.

The R is basically an integer saying how far the message should go.

```
e.g. 0 = broadcast the message to self,
     1 = broadcast the message to the friends of the pid,
     2 = broadcast the message to the friends of the friends of the pid and so on...
```

What I get from the terminal after I setup the Pid, set the "friendships" between the Pids and broadcast a message is:

```
1> f().
ok
2> c(facein).
facein.erl:72: Warning: variable 'From' is unused
{ok,facein}
3> {Message, Pid} = facein:start({"dummy", [], []}).
{ok,<0.186.0>}
4> {Message, Pid2} = facein:start({"dummy2", [], []}).
{ok,<0.188.0>}
5> facein:add_friend(Pid,Pid2).
ok
6> facein:broadcast(Pid,"hello",1).    
=ERROR REPORT==== 5-Oct-2014::12:12:58 ===
Error in process <0.186.0> with exit value: {if_clause,[{facein,looper,1,[{file,"facein.erl"},{line,74}]}]}

{<0.177.0>,{send_message,{"hello",1,#Ref<0.0.0.914>}}}
```

When I view the messages of the Pid that broadcasted the message, then the console just hangs and the other Pids have no messages received.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: not enough detail here, the looper function isn't even valid erlang (missing receive).

Comment: I added the receive in the looper (my bad). What other information do you need? maybe I can give you that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### error message

This time what you get is `if_clause` error.  In Erlang every expression have to return some value, `if` included.  Meaning that you could write code like this

```
SomeVar = if 
     R =< 0 ->
       [...]
     R > 0 andalso FriendTale =/= []->
       [...]
  end
```

As you can see if needs to "return" something, and to do that, one of it's branches needs to run.  Or in other words one of it's clauses needs to mach. But in your case, when `R > 0` and `FriendsTale =:= []` non of them does.  Hence an run-time error.

As general practive last of clauses is left as

```
  _ ->  
     [...]
```

which will always match, and save you from such error.

In you example you don't have to use `if` at all.  What you could do is to extend you receive clauses with some guards

```
looper({Name, Friends, Messages}) ->
  receive
    {From, {send_message, {M, R, ID, [{FriendPid, FriendName} | FriendTale]}}} 
       when R =< 0 ->
          From ! {From, {self(), {ID, M}}},
          looper({Name, [{FriendPid, FriendName} | FriendTale], [{ID, M} | Messages]});
    {From, {send_message, {M, R, ID, [{FriendPid, FriendName} | FriendTale]}}}  
       when R > 0  andalso FriendTale =/= [] ->
          FriendPid ! {From, {send_message, {M, R-1, ID, FriendTale}}},
          looper({Name, FriendTale, [{ID, M} | Messages]});
    terminate ->
          ok
  end.
```

In case of `receive` message that is received do not have to match to one clauses.  And if it does not, it is just left in message box (ignored in this receive, but could be caught by another).

Or fallowing you logic you could pattern match on `R` itself

```
looper({Name, Friends, Messages}) ->
  receive
    {From, {send_message, {M, 0, ID, [{FriendPid, FriendName} | FriendTale]}}} ->
          From ! {From, {self(), {ID, M}}},
          looper({Name, [{FriendPid, FriendName} | FriendTale], [{ID, M} | Messages]});
    {From, {send_message, {M, 1, ID, [{FriendPid, FriendName} | FriendTale]}}}  
       when FriendTale =/= [] ->
          FriendPid ! {From, {send_message, {M, R-1, ID, FriendTale}}},
          looper({Name, FriendTale, [{ID, M} | Messages]});
    terminate ->
          ok
  end.
```

And to increase readybility, you could change `R` from opque integer, to miningfull atoms

```
looper({Name, Friends, Messages}) ->
  receive
    {From, {send_message, {M, back_to_me, ID, [{FriendPid, FriendName} | FriendTale]}}} ->
          From ! {From, {self(), {ID, M}}},
          looper({Name, [{FriendPid, FriendName} | FriendTale], [{ID, M} | Messages]});

    {From, {send_message, {M, to_friends, ID, [{FriendPid, FriendName} | FriendTale]}}}  
       when FriendTale =/= [] ->
          FriendPid ! {From, {send_message, {M, R-1, ID, FriendTale}}},
          looper({Name, FriendTale, [{ID, M} | Messages]});

    terminate ->
          ok
  end.
```

#### broadcast to friends

If I understand correctly `looper` is function representing one "person".  Each friend is process that stores list  of friends, can add and remove from it, and can send messages to another friends.

Lets start from creating clause for each of those functions (creating process interface)

```
looper(Name, Friends, Messages) ->
  receive 
     {add_friend, Friend} ->
        [...];
     {remove_friend, Friend} ->
        [...];
     {receive_message, Message} ->
        [...];frineds
     {broadcast_to_self, Message} ->
        [...];
     {broadcast_to_friends, Message} ->
        [...];
     terminate ->
        ok
  end
```

Most of those are easily implemented, like

```
{add_frined, Friend} ->
    looper(Name, [Friend, Friends], Messages);
```

so I will not go into details.

The ones that do the broadcast do not change state, so for now lets write something like this (mostly for sake of readability

```
     {broadcast_to_friends, Message} ->
        handle_broadcast_to_friends(Friends, Message),
        looper(Name, Friends, Messages);
```

and implement new function below

```
handle_broadcast_to_friends(Friends, Message) ->
   [ F ! {receive_message, Message} || F <- Friends ].
```

Now, since knowing exactly what tuple with which atoms to send is not convenient, we could wrap our "message interface" into "funciton interface". For example

```
add_friend(Person,  Friend) ->
   Person ! {add_friend, Friends}.

receive_message(Person, Message) ->
    Person ! {receive_message, Message}.
```

And we could use those also in your logic implementation

```
handle_broadcast_to_friends(Friends, Message) ->
   [ receive_message(F, Message)  || F <- Friends ].
```

That should start you on wright track. If you need `MessageID` or something like that, just extend your interface.  If you really need to create `broadcast_to_all`, you need to think how would you handle messages circling around, which is a not simple problem.

Comment: But is my syntax correct for trying to pass the message to a list of processes?

Comment: I added another pattern in the receive block because saw again the error report and line 74 that it mentions is this line: `From ! {self(), Friends},`

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you reduce the complexity of what you are doing to just the essentials first. This conditional processing business in your receive is not part of your basic messaging issue, for example. Here is a basic example of a common broadcast idiom, using a list comprehension to send to a list of pids in the function `bcast/2`:

```
-module(bcast).
-export([start/0]).

start() ->
    Pids = [spawn(fun() -> listener() end) || _ <- lists:seq(1,3)],
    Message = "This is my message.",
    ok = bcast(Pids, Message),
    timer:sleep(100), % Give the subordinates time to act.
    [exit(P, kill) || P <- Pids],
    ok.

listener() ->
    receive
        {bcast, Message} ->
            Now = now(),
            io:format(user, "~p ~p: Received: ~p~n", [self(), now(), Message]),
            listener();
        Any ->
            io:format(user, "~p HURR! Unexpected message: ~p~n", [self(), Any]),
            listener()
    end.

bcast(Pids, Message) ->
    BCast = fun(Pid) -> send(Pid, {bcast, Message}) end,
    lists:foreach(BCast, Pids).
```

The other issues you are having in your code aren't really broadcast issues, they are problems with getting ahead of yourself in an unfamiliar language.

This example is asynchronous (we're only sending a message one way) and requires we kill our subordinate processes because I've only written an infinite loop. Those aspects are the first things to play with: how to deal with your *message queue* (as in, the whole mailbox) not just send a message, receive a message in a loop; and think about how you want your subordinate processes to die when things go right (I just murder them all in the example above).

**EDIT**
It is good to know that there is another, somewhat common, way of writing the `bcast/2` function above using a list comprehension that is assigned to the "I don't care" variable `_`:

```
bcast(Pids, Message) ->
    _ = [P ! {bcast, Message} || P <- Pids],
    ok.
```

I used to prefer this list comprehension style because it was the first style I was introduced to -- but over the last several years I've become a big fan of the semantic correctness of `lists:foreach/2`. The point is to not get confused when you see a list comprehension -- it is an important expression type to be able to read!

Comment: This code seems to send message n times instead of broadcasting.

Comment: @user7860670 The bcast/2 function is where to find the actual broadcast send. The line `_ = [P ! {bcast, Message} || P <- Pids],` could be rewritten as `BCast = fun(P) -> send(P, {bcast, Message}) end, lists:foreach(BCast, Pids).` I'll add a note as an alternative.

Comment: Either way message is sent using usual send expression `!`, so no broadcast happens. When i was looking for a broadcast i was hoping to find some method that would allow me to send to multiple processes without increasing the cast with each additional recipient.

Comment: @user7860670 Nothing in computers is instant. One thing is always happening after another thing as long as you are in a single context. What do you expect to happen? The scheduler process that is executing the running process's code is going to be able to magically write to an arbitrary number of memory addresses at the same time? The best we could do is _hide_ this from you, but that's silly.

Comment: I expect that sending a broadcast message would involve creation of a single message regardless of number of recipients (at least when they reside in the same OS process). This is what happens in proper single-writer multi-reader message queues. However erlang implementation seems to involve only single-writer single-reader queues so broadcasting is not possible. Even the `pg` module that is seemingly suitable for providing broadcast functionality explicitly states that "There are no special functions for sending a message to the process group."

Comment: @user7860670 "in proper single-writer multi-reader messages queues" <- This comment makes no sense for a rather large number of reasons.

Comment: Well, if you are not familiar with single-writer multi-reader messages queues then you certainly should try them out.

Comment: @user7860670 There are no words...