# Error in broadcasting a message to processes in Erlang

Tags: erlang, erlang-shell

I am new to Erlang and I am trying to make a Pid send a message to several other Pids.

I have a function that takes as arguments a Pid, a string(message) and an integer R(radius).

```
broadcast(P, M, R) ->
  P ! {self(), friends},
  receive
    {P, Friends} ->
      [F ! {{broadcast, P, M, R}, Friends} || F <- Friends],
      ok;
    {} ->
  end.
```

I have this listener function that waits for new messages to be received:

```
looper({Name, Friends, Messages}) ->
  receive
    {From, friends} ->
       From ! {self(), Friends},
       looper({Name, Friends, Messages});
    {{broadcast, ID, M, R}, Friends}  ->
       % From ! {From, {self(), {ID, M}}},
       looper({Name, Friends, [{ID, M} | Messages]});
    terminate ->
      ok
  end.
```

When I call the function broadcast I get this message:

```
faceinsok:broadcast(Pid, "asd", 1).                     
** exception error: bad argument
     in function  faceinsok:'-broadcast/3-lc$^0/1-0-'/5 (faceinsok.erl, line 56)
```

line 56 is the line:

```
[F ! {{broadcast, P, M, R}, Friends} || F <- Friends],
```

From what I understand I don't pass correctly the message :/
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to broadcast a message to a list of processes in Erlang? Console hanging](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26202576/how-to-broadcast-a-message-to-a-list-of-processes-in-erlang-console-hanging)

Comment: "Improved" code different error message, so I don't think it can be considered as duplicate

Comment: You aren't having a broadcast problem, you are having pattern matching/type problems.

Answer (score 1):

Again. In line 55 you are receiving `{P, Friends}`, and assume that `Friends` is a list.  But I guess it is not, since in line 53 you are sending `{self(), friends}`.  And you can not do list comphenetion on atom `friends`.

You should add guard checking if `Friends` is actually a list.

```
  receive
    {P, Friends} when is_list(Friends) ->
      [F ! {{broadcast, P, M, R}, Friends} || F <- Friends],
      ok;
    {} ->
```

and than check if it's working the way you think it is.

Comment: Actually `Friends` is always a list. In line 53 I send a message with the "string" friends and the looper receives that and sends back the list `Friends`. Am I not doing this right? :/

Comment: You think that it is a list (of Pid's), or it should be a list. Try to print it just before line 56, and see what it is, just like in the simplest debugging.

Comment: It should be a list of {Pid, String}. Maybe I don't do a correct pattern match?

Comment: What do you mean by `String` ? And pleas just check what is actual value of variable, that's easiest way to do it.

Comment: @mpm: The problem is of course in `Friends`, which is not a list, but what the fact that `friends` is an atom has nothing to do with it. Other than that your reply is correct.